# Select day of links laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to make a modal with a select of day that the links are showed... Showing the 10 past days and paginate with scroll... How can I do it? Carbon? If yes, I don't know how, because I'm beginner.

VIEW:

```
<div class="white-balloon" id="selectday-balloon">
            <ul id="selectday-scroll">
                <!--current day = 19/02/2018-->
                <!--past days-->
                <li rel="18/02/2016"><h1>Yesterday</h1></li>
                <li rel="17/02/2016"><h1>17/02/2018</h1></li>
                <li rel="16/02/2016"><h1>16/02/2018</h1></li>
                <li rel="15/02/2016"><h1>15/02/2018</h1></li>
                <li rel="14/02/2016"><h1>14/02/2018</h1></li>
                <li rel="13/02/2016"><h1>13/02/2018</h1></li>
                <li rel="12/02/2016"><h1>12/02/2018</h1></li>
                <li rel="11/02/2016"><h1>11/02/2018</h1></li>
                <li rel="10/02/2016"><h1>10/02/2018</h1></li>
                <li rel="09/02/2016"><h1>09/02/2018</h1></li>
                <!--continue in paginate-->
            </ul>
        </div>
```

JQUERY LOAD MORE:

```
$('#selectday-scroll').bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
        var isLoading = false;
        var last_day = $("#selectday-scroll li").last().attr("rel");

        if (isLoading === false) {
            var isLoading = true; 
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.origin + '/balloons/selectday/',
            dataType: "HTML",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {last_day: last_day},
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#selectday-scroll').append(response);
                var isLoading = false; 
            }
        });
    }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `for` loop for that, try below code. This code is controller code, you need to add `lastDays` in view return statement.

```
$today = Carbon::today();
$lastDays = array();

for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $day = $today->subDays(1)->format('d/m/Y');
    $lastDays[] = $day;
}
```

Comment: `$lastDays` is array of dates, you need to write loop in view file too, to show dates.

Comment: strange that in another controller, the same code returns the correct date.

Comment: Anytime !!, **happy coding :)**

Answer (score 0):

Try  this, at the end you have an array with the dates.

You can change de format like you wnat.

```
    $today = Carbon::now();
    $days  = 10;

    for($i = 0; $i <= $days; $i++)
    {
       $date = '';
       // $date = $today->addDays($i); if you want add day
       $date = $today->subDays($i);
       $arrayDate[] = $date->format('Y-m-d') ;
    }
```

[Carbon Documentation](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)